How may I get reasonable lattice constants of hybrid halide perovskite material ((BA)2PbBr4 here) using SIESTA?
I am relaxing the structures of hybrid halide perovskite material,(BA)2PbBr4 here. I tried to use GGA-PBE or LDA-PW92 exchange functionals, and pseudopotential files come from http://www.pseudo-dojo.org/. I tried to increase Mesh.Cutoff and k-points density, but make no difference. DFT-D3 is included here.
The following is the input file,
SystemName 4517593.poscar
SystemLabel 4517593.poscar

NumberOfAtoms 156
NumberOfSpecies 5

%block Chemical_Species_label
1 82 Pb
2 35 Br
3 7 N
4 1 H
5 6 C
%endblock Chemical_Species_label

LatticeConstant 1.0 Ang
%block LatticeVectors
 8.3343000412 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
 0.0000000000 8.2224998474 0.0000000000
 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 27.6170997620
%endblock LatticeVectors


AtomicCoordinatesFormat Ang
%block  AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
4.1672 4.1112 13.8085 1
0.0000 0.0000 13.8085 1
0.0000 4.1112 0.0000 1
4.1672 0.0000 0.0000 1
6.7099 1.5960 27.5453 2
5.7915 5.7072 27.5453 2
3.8805 8.0589 24.6206 2
0.2867 3.9476 24.6206 2
8.0476 8.0589 16.8050 2
4.4538 3.9476 16.8050 2
1.6244 5.7072 13.8804 2
2.5428 1.5960 13.8804 2
5.7915 6.6265 13.7367 2
6.7099 2.5153 13.7367 2
0.2867 0.1636 10.8121 2
3.8805 4.2749 10.8121 2
8.0476 4.2749 2.9965 2
4.4538 0.1636 2.9965 2
1.6244 6.6265 0.0718 2
2.5428 2.5153 0.0718 2
3.5504 4.7082 25.1592 3
0.6167 0.5970 25.1592 3
4.7839 0.5970 16.2665 3
7.7176 4.7082 16.2665 3
3.5504 7.6255 11.3506 3
0.6167 3.5143 11.3506 3
7.7176 7.6255 2.4579 3
4.7839 3.5143 2.4579 3
0.4842 0.5082 26.0346 4
3.6829 4.6194 26.0346 4
1.4477 0.3478 24.9576 4
2.7195 4.4591 24.9576 4
0.4976 1.4480 24.9244 4
3.6696 5.5592 24.9244 4
8.1034 7.0500 24.7090 4
4.3980 2.9387 24.7090 4
5.4115 4.1343 24.6483 4
7.0900 0.0230 24.6483 4
3.4054 3.6919 22.7399 4
0.7618 7.8032 22.7399 4
4.4430 4.8677 22.6764 4
8.0584 0.7565 22.6764 4
5.1489 2.1387 22.5162 4
7.3525 6.2499 22.5162 4
6.3132 7.4241 22.4555 4
6.1882 3.3128 22.4555 4
1.5052 2.5161 21.1105 4
2.6620 6.6273 21.1105 4
1.1410 4.0348 20.9724 4
3.0262 8.1460 20.9724 4
0.0133 2.9486 20.8951 4
4.1538 7.0598 20.8951 4
4.1805 2.9486 20.5306 4
8.3210 7.0598 20.5306 4
7.1933 8.1460 20.4532 4
5.3081 4.0348 20.4532 4
6.8291 6.6273 20.3151 4
5.6723 2.5161 20.3151 4
2.1461 7.4241 18.9702 4
2.0211 3.3128 18.9702 4
0.9818 2.1387 18.9094 4
3.1854 6.2499 18.9094 4
0.2759 4.8677 18.7492 4
3.8913 0.7565 18.7492 4
7.5725 3.6919 18.6857 4
4.9289 7.8032 18.6857 4
1.2443 4.1343 16.7774 4
2.9228 0.0230 16.7774 4
3.9363 7.0500 16.7166 4
0.2309 2.9387 16.7166 4
7.8367 5.5592 16.5012 4
4.6647 1.4480 16.5012 4
5.6148 0.3478 16.4681 4
6.8866 4.4591 16.4681 4
7.8501 4.6194 15.3910 4
4.6514 0.5082 15.3910 4
0.4842 3.6031 12.2261 4
3.6829 7.7143 12.2261 4
2.7195 7.8747 11.1490 4
1.4477 3.7634 11.1490 4
3.6696 6.7745 11.1159 4
0.4976 2.6633 11.1159 4
4.3980 1.1725 10.9005 4
8.1034 5.2838 10.9005 4
5.4115 8.1995 10.8397 4
7.0900 4.0882 10.8397 4
3.4054 0.4193 8.9314 4
0.7618 4.5306 8.9314 4
4.4430 7.4660 8.8679 4
8.0584 3.3548 8.8679 4
7.3525 6.0838 8.7077 4
5.1489 1.9726 8.7077 4
6.1882 0.7984 8.6469 4
6.3132 4.9097 8.6469 4
1.5052 1.5952 7.3020 4
2.6620 5.7064 7.3020 4
1.1410 0.0765 7.1639 4
3.0262 4.1877 7.1639 4
0.0133 1.1627 7.0865 4
4.1538 5.2739 7.0865 4
8.3210 5.2739 6.7220 4
4.1805 1.1627 6.7220 4
7.1933 4.1877 6.6447 4
5.3081 0.0765 6.6447 4
6.8291 5.7064 6.5066 4
5.6723 1.5952 6.5066 4
2.0211 0.7984 5.1616 4
2.1461 4.9097 5.1616 4
0.9818 1.9726 5.1009 4
3.1854 6.0838 5.1009 4
3.8913 3.3548 4.9407 4
0.2759 7.4660 4.9407 4
4.9289 4.5306 4.8772 4
7.5725 0.4193 4.8772 4
1.2443 8.1995 2.9688 4
2.9228 4.0882 2.9688 4
3.9363 5.2838 2.9081 4
0.2309 1.1725 2.9081 4
7.8367 6.7745 2.6927 4
4.6647 2.6633 2.6927 4
5.6148 3.7634 2.6595 4
6.8866 7.8747 2.6595 4
7.8501 7.7143 1.5825 4
4.6514 3.6031 1.5825 4
7.9934 7.9717 24.4273 5
4.5080 3.8605 24.4273 5
8.1876 8.0613 22.9609 5
4.3138 3.9501 22.9609 5
7.2208 7.1684 22.2290 5
5.2806 3.0571 22.2290 5
7.4075 7.2580 20.7515 5
5.0939 3.1468 20.7515 5
3.2404 7.2580 20.6742 5
0.9268 3.1468 20.6742 5
1.1135 3.0571 19.1966 5
3.0537 7.1684 19.1966 5
0.1467 3.9501 18.4648 5
4.0205 8.0613 18.4648 5
0.3409 3.8605 16.9983 5
3.8263 7.9717 16.9983 5
7.9934 4.3620 10.6188 5
4.5080 0.2508 10.6188 5
8.1876 4.2724 9.1523 5
4.3138 0.1612 9.1523 5
5.2806 1.0541 8.4205 5
7.2208 5.1654 8.4205 5
5.0939 0.9645 6.9429 5
7.4075 5.0757 6.9429 5
0.9268 0.9645 6.8656 5
3.2404 5.0757 6.8656 5
3.0537 5.1654 5.3881 5
1.1135 1.0541 5.3881 5
0.1467 0.1612 4.6562 5
4.0205 4.2724 4.6562 5
3.8263 4.3620 3.1898 5
0.3409 0.2508 3.1898 5
%endblock  AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies



%block kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
  6   0   0    0.0
  0   6   0    0.0
  0   0   2    0.0
%endblock kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack



    # -- SELF-CONSISTENT FIELD --

Mesh.Cutoff         200 Ry
PAO.BasisType       split
PAO.BasisSize       DZP
XC.functional           GGA
XC.authors              PBE
MaxSCFIterations        100
SolutionMethod          diagon
DFTD3                   T
    # -- SELF-CONSISTENT FIELD-MIXING --

SCF.Mixer.Weight        0.25
SCF.Mixer.Method        Pulay
SCF.Mixer.History       10
SCF.Mix.AfterConvergence false



# -- MOLECULAR DYNAMICS-CONJUGATE-GRADIENT-METHOD --

MD.TypeOfRun             CG
MD.VariableCell          true
MD.MaxForceTol           0.05 eV/Ang
#MD.MaxStressTol          1 GPa
MD.Steps                 300
MD.MaxDispl              0.2 Bohr

Experimental lattice constants from reference 'DOI: 10.1126/science.aac7660'
a = 8.2530(2) Å a= 90°.
b = 8.1375(2) Å b= 90°.
c = 27.4028(9) Å g = 90°.

And grep 'Cell vector modules' gives
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.334300    8.222500   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.381996    8.273940   27.614189
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.458309    8.356244   27.609532
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.580409    8.487931   27.602080
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.741786    8.661978   27.592231
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.650932    8.563991   27.597776
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.485768    8.389945   27.445923
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.320604    8.215899   27.294071
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.155440    8.041852   27.142219
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.990276    7.867806   26.990366
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.825112    7.693760   26.838514
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.933168    7.807627   26.937861
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.791944    7.633581   26.403253
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.650720    7.459534   25.868644
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.509496    7.285488   25.334035
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.562665    7.351014   25.535310
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.559290    7.364405   26.119883
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.555916    7.377795   26.704456
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.556510    7.375437   26.601522
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.411281    7.272957   26.016949
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.266052    7.170477   25.432375
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.120823    7.067998   24.847802
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.234433    7.148166   25.305103
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.099209    6.974119   24.836005
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    6.963985    6.800073   24.366906

It was obvious that the lattice constant was getting further and further away from the experimental lattice constant,so I stopped calculating.
I noticed some excellent works from Dr.Boubacar Traoré claim that like DOI: 10.1021/acsenergylett.1c02459
    DFT-based calculations were performed using SIESTA using a basis set of finite- 
    range of numerical atomic orbitals. For structural optimization, we used the van 
    der Waals density functional with C09 exchange within the van der Waals DF2 flavor 
    to describe the exchange-correlation term (we modified SIESTA version "masterpost- 
    4.1-251" to include DF2 flavor in which Zab = −1:887 instead of Zab = −0:8491 in 
    DF1). This tuning was suggested to improve C09 based geometry optimization over 
    that with the original DF1 flavor. The latter has already proven to provide a good 
    description of experimental lattice constants similar to those obtained with 
    optimized GGA based PBEsol functional in solids.

But libxc library can't be compiled with siesta in our workstation, so I can't use van der Waals density functional with C09 exchange.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

The problem is finally solved by changing pseudopotential source from http://www.pseudo-dojo.org/ to https://www.simuneatomistics.com/siesta-pro/siesta-pseudos-and-basis-database/
To make the answer more detailed:
After changing the pseudopotential files,(without changing the input file),grep 'Cell vector modules' out gives:
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.357000    8.238000   27.659000
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.445447    8.325187   27.951731
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.533894    8.412374   28.244461
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.445447    8.325187   28.537191
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.357000    8.238000   28.829921
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.393707    8.287486   28.724522
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.433345    8.341624   28.595314
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.471396    8.395859   28.425451
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.488754    8.426353   28.243674
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.480089    8.415887   28.254359
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.469422    8.402987   28.267534
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.454958    8.385448   28.285476
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.437197    8.363820   28.307689
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.416832    8.338850   28.333578
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.394810    8.311541   28.362487
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.372589    8.283417   28.393663
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.352640    8.257170   28.425620
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.353223    8.257662   28.425903
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.353949    8.258273   28.426259
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.354954    8.259116   28.426764
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.356225    8.260180   28.427425
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.357748    8.261447   28.428255
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.359501    8.262895   28.429268
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.361457    8.264496   28.430485
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.363587    8.266219   28.431928
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.366090    8.268212   28.433807
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.368983    8.270466   28.436265
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.372251    8.272937   28.439495
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.375836    8.275526   28.443754
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.379601    8.278061   28.449370
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.383326    8.280286   28.456728
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.386709    8.281878   28.466228
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.389409    8.282488   28.478253
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.391087    8.281798   28.493135
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.391469    8.279586   28.511116
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.390451    8.275848   28.532248
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.388285    8.271021   28.556168
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.385884    8.266332   28.581652
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.384968    8.263930   28.606261
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.387450    8.266152   28.626884
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.394738    8.274776   28.640253
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.406933    8.290255   28.643022
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.420160    8.308710   28.633706
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.417794    8.306428   28.632888
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.414965    8.303713   28.631800
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.411373    8.300298   28.630100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.407449    8.296627   28.627593
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.403777    8.293299   28.624128
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.400874    8.290837   28.619755
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.399026    8.289514   28.614667
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.398303    8.289381   28.609096
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.398644    8.290425   28.602693
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.399933    8.292523   28.595720
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.401538    8.295005   28.588765
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.402251    8.296597   28.582669
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.400800    8.295955   28.578138
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.396227    8.292079   28.575492
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.388635    8.285102   28.574131
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.381026    8.278237   28.571560
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.377117    8.275454   28.565395
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.379341    8.279463   28.554256
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.384328    8.286966   28.541037
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.379559    8.281993   28.545047
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.374442    8.276668   28.549546
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.370090    8.272195   28.554028
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.371071    8.273250   28.553499
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.372260    8.274530   28.552854
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.373821    8.276214   28.552000
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.375634    8.278180   28.550991
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.377521    8.280241   28.549912
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.379237    8.282139   28.548888
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.380582    8.283659   28.548029
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.381456    8.284692   28.547399
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.381847    8.285236   28.546988
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.381628    8.285156   28.546867
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.380700    8.284350   28.547092
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.379070    8.282829   28.547667
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.377033    8.280909   28.548432
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.375363    8.279411   28.548955
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.374862    8.279184   28.548738
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.376177    8.280917   28.547281
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.379519    8.284847   28.544109
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.383639    8.289707   28.539205
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.385661    8.292504   28.533981
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.383354    8.290922   28.529775
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.376591    8.284846   28.526982
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.372448    8.281659   28.522272
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.377601    8.288359   28.511511
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.391633    8.304799   28.491217
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.380746    8.293628   28.494929
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.370131    8.282791   28.498124
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.372214    8.284959   28.497156
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.374693    8.287544   28.495985
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.377809    8.290802   28.494457
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.381105    8.294274   28.492683
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.380997    8.294171   28.492672
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.380864    8.294043   28.492658
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.380683    8.293869   28.492637
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.380460    8.293655   28.492607
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.380202    8.293408   28.492566
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.379920    8.293139   28.492510
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.379624    8.292860   28.492436
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.379328    8.292585   28.492340
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.379017    8.292301   28.492205
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.378710    8.292029   28.492018
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.378431    8.291796   28.491762
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.378211    8.291636   28.491417
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.378086    8.291586   28.490958
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.378089    8.291685   28.490348
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.378243    8.291958   28.489564
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.378541    8.292404   28.488584
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.378924    8.292965   28.487387
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.379259    8.293510   28.485974
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.379359    8.293856   28.484367
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.379054    8.293834   28.482580
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.378300    8.293409   28.480588
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.378300    8.293409   28.480588


I got a convergenced result after 116 geom steps.
The constants deviated from experimental results,but it is acceptable to some extent

To make this answer more substantial, more helpful to future users, and to at least attempt to maintain this site's quality standards, can you please try to expand this answer? For example, maybe you could include an input/output combination that demonstrates how this solved your problem?  Please take a look at this question/answer combination of mine, as an example of what I mean.
